# Laravel hasmanythrough where statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to get the projects by the `Auth::user()` and `company_id`. I created the following:

Database:

```
projects:
    - id
    - name
    - company_id
project_users:
    - id
    - project_id
    - user_id
users:
    - id
    - name
    - email
companies:
    - id
    - name
```

So I want to get the current user projects which belongs to company_id.

I tried the following with `User Modal -> return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ProjectUsers', 'App\Project')`. `$user->projects->where('company_id', 1)` but it returns all the data (also with company_id 2,3,4 etc).

I'm looking for a solution which can filter the projects with company_id 1 out of the query.

Comment: Is the hasManyThrough returned from your User model's projects method?

Comment: The hasManyThrough is returned from the User model.

Comment: You should just post your User model code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create function in model of user

```
public function projectusers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\project_users', 'projectID')->with('companies');
    }
```

now create function in model projects

```
public function companies() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\companies','id', 'company_id');
}
```

Comment: How do I get the projects only where `company = 1`?

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\Models\companies','id', 'company_id')->where('company', 1);

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to limit a relation based on the results of another relation, then you need to use `whereHas`.

Also if you want to get the projects by some condition, I find its often most helpful to start there, with the projects.

```
$projects = App\Project::whereHas('company', function($q) use ($company_id) {
    $q->where('id', $company_id);
})->with('users')->get();
```

This will grab only the projects belonging to a certain company and also eager load the users.

As you are looping, then you can get the count of the users using the relation.

```
foreach ($projects as $project) {
    echo 'Num User: '.$project->users->count();
}
```

Comment: The user(s) that are linked to the projects are in a separate table, project_users. The project can have 0 or more users.

Comment: Oh I see what you are saying, I think this is close to what you want but how do you get a project by the users if there can be 0, 1, or many users?

Comment: I want a page where the system admin can see how many projects a user has. So for example `user1 is assigned to 6 projects` and `user2 is assigned to 1 project`. That's the reason for this. But the system admin from company 1 is not allowed to see if the user is linked to another company and how many projects they have.

Comment: Okay that makes more sense, you just want to load the users along with the projects after you've already limited the projects based on the company id.  I've updated the code.